# Running a quick Javascript benchmark on first load

Tags: javascript, css, animation

What I would like to do is run a simple and fast Javascript benchmark when a user first access my web application to detect his computer's capacity to animate elements. I remember a teacher did this in college to adapt the frame rate of his game depending on the user's machine.

Is it something that could be done without sacrificing too much user resources? Maybe a few seconds after the page is loaded? And if the results are not good, we just disable some or all animations for this user.

Comment: would be good to use a test that represents what will be done - how are you animating elements?

Comment: Most of the elements are animated via jQuery.animate() or simple CSS3 transitions in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the questions that you asked in your post:

1) It is possible to run a JavaScript benchmark when a person first loads your site that will test their capacity for CSS/JavaScript animation speeds, but it *will* sacrifice several resources.  You have to consider the people who will be accessing your site.  If they're going to be accessing your site via a mobile device, the last thing you want to do is bring their device to a standstill and either freeze their browser or bump other apps out of memory.  You don't want either a desktop *or* mobile user to think that the site is unresponsive.

2) One of the issues with waiting a few seconds after the page has loaded is that, depending on what you want to do with the site, people will start to try to scroll through your content.  If they start to scroll and realize that the site is "stuttering", they may think that something is wrong with their device.

Another caveat is that if you want the smoothest animations possible, you may end up using requestAnimationFrame (see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/). If somebody loads your site and then clicks away from it to a different tab while your test is running, browsers have adopted the practice of reducing the framerate in inactive tabs in favor of those in the active tab.  Testing based on this (incorrect) framerate capability will result in parts of your site being disabled for people who are perfectly capable of running your site with all of the animations intact, so that's something you may need to take into account.

In some tests that I ran a couple of months ago, the CSS3 version of an animation was almost always smoother than the JavaScript version of an animation.  However, there are now jQuery libraries that bridge this gap by using CSS3 animations when possible, such as jQuery Transit (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/).